# Generator control from outside of a generator (networkx simple_cycles)

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator, networkx

I am using NetworkX's simple_cycles to generate all cycles, and I iterate through on the condition of breaking if a cycle of size k is found (k being supplied by the user).

```
try:
    for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G):
        if len(cycle) == k:
            checkval = True
            break
    if not checkval:
        print "no path of size k"
except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
    print "There was no path of size k"
    checkval = False
```

Depending on the graph, simple_cycles may take basically forever to try to find a cycle of size k.  I would like to stop checking after a certain amount of time.  I can't stop based on the amount of cycles found, because that is unreliable.  Sometimes 1 cycle may be found in a full minute, and 100000 cycles may be found in 30 seconds.

My question is if there is a way to stop the generator based on a certain amount of time passing, from OUTSIDE of the generator.. or if the only way would be to modify the code of the generator itself.

(Also any general advice about what I am trying to do would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that there are pathological corner cases ... for example, a huge, huge graph with zero cycles, such that it requires too much time before even the first iteration of `nx.simple_cycles(G)` can complete.

As a result, there won't be a way to do it from *outside* the generator unless you place the execution into another context that you are able to terminate, like a separate `Process` from `multiprocessing`, or [running the coroutine with asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading).

Then for each cycle that is asynchronously obtained (either from the process or thread), you can check the length condition *and* a condition on the overall amount of elapsed time, and choose to terminate the other process / thread if you exceed the time limit.

On the other hand, if you don't care about this type of corner case and you're reasonably sure that the values yielded by `nx.simple_cycles(G)` will return in reasonable amounts of time, then you could wrap that generator to make your own time-limited generator:

```
import time


def time_limited_cycles(G, time_limit=100.0):
    elapsed, cycle_generator = 0.0, nx.simple_cycles(G)
    while elapsed <= time_limit:
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            # crucial assumption here, that calling next on
            # the original generator never takes too long.
            cycle = next(cycle_generator)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        yield cycle
        elapsed += time.time() - start_time 
        # move elapsed above the yield line if you are looking
        # to limit the internal runtime of the generator, rather
        # than overall time spent processing cycles.
```

With the above, you can replace your original usage of `nx.simple_cycles` with a call to `time_limited_cycles` instead (with your desired time limit), and the rest of your code will work the same, because `time_limited_cycles` yields the same cycle results that `nx.simple_cycles` would yield, up to the point that it stops.

Answer (score 0):

The part where you check the length looks like a good place to start. Using `time` is also a good idea for timing things. At the top of your code, insert:

```
from time import time
```

Before the `for` loop, insert:

```
time_to_wait = int (time()) + x # x is the time you want to wait.
```

In your `for` loop, change the `if` statement to:

```
if len (cycle) == k or int (time()) == time_to_wait
```

You might want to make another `if` instead of merging it because a timeout will still set `checkval` to True, which you may not want. In that case, just leave the first `if` alone, and make another one:

```
if int (time()) == time_to_wait: break
```